# Как определить ориентацию экрана Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть два Canvas с разными видами расширениями кнопок "Portrait" и "Landscape"
нужно определить в какой ориентации девайс и включить соответствующее меню

**My Code (не работает)**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class DeviceOrientation : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Portrait_Menu;
public GameObject LandscapeLeft_Menu;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Portrait_Menu.SetActive(false);
    LandscapeLeft_Menu.SetActive(false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait) {
        Portrait_Menu.SetActive(true);
        LandscapeLeft_Menu.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)    {
        Portrait_Menu.SetActive(false);
        LandscapeLeft_Menu.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Используя [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-deviceOrientation.html). 
Рассмотрите вариант [контроля ориентации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html) или стандартизации, это сэкономит время на поддержку вариантов меню.

```
if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait) {
    // портретная ориентация
}
```

репо: приложение с примером https://github.com/Tokatak/Test-MobileOrientation

Comment: вижу вы понимаете, покажите на примере пожалуйста

Comment: Регулировать доступные повороты можно [прямо из редактора](https://pasteboard.co/HnfZpje.png). Если речь идет о маштабируемом интерфейсе то легкое [интро](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwZfv_17KN8) а в идеале [ознакомится с официальным курсом](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui)

Comment: У меня есть двух видов меню "Portrait" и "Landscape" как мне определить какая ориентация используется чтобы включить нужное меню ?

Comment: Написал же в первой ссылке в ответе https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-deviceOrientation.html перечисление всех ориентаций https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html

Comment: покажите на примере кода

Comment: не работает ваш пример

Comment: Нет, все работает репо : https://github.com/Tokatak/Test-MobileOrientation

Comment: то что вы кинули при запуске выдает `Unknown`

Comment: Вероятно проблема в устройстве, пробовали запускать на другом?

Comment: на каком устройстве вы тестировали ?

Comment: Samsung S5 и Samsung Tab 3

Comment: OK. а как сделать чтобы ещё и ПК работало ?

Comment: Простите, на Пк вы монтор собрались крутить ? Опишите как вы себе это представляете.

Comment: например при смены разрешения экрана с 1080 x 1920 на 1920 x 1080

Comment: Сделайте прослойку котрую можно контролировать с редактора,  или отбейте [платформо зависимой компиляцией](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). Возможно получится запустить билд на эмулятор.